# Can I install Android on my Dell XT Tablet with multitouch?

Tags: android, tablet

So I heard that ntrig has released Android drivers for their multitouch interface.

I am sick of Windows 7 on my Dell XT Tablet, and if some one, some where has made the switch to Android, I would love a how-to and get it going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) is the primary project for anyone attempting to run the Android OS on an x86-based system.

At a glance, it looks like you can boot and use the OS, but no WiFi or touchscreen support.  [Google Groups Search](http://groups.google.com/group/android-x86/search?group=android-x86&q=Dell%20Latitude%20XT&qt_g=Search%20this%20group).  Also, I'm not sure the Google Apps (e.g. GMail, **Market**, etc.) are available.  It looks like the Market isn't available by default, but it's possible to hack in support, kinda.  Maybe.

If I had to venture a guess, I'd say that right now it's probably not in a state where you could use it as your primary OS.  Someday it will probably get there, but not right now.  You'd probably be better off with a Linux variant if you want to get away from Windows.

Comment: i actually looked here sometime ago.. I am not sure why no one has tried this. Prolly have to create some time to give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_devices) of all known devices supported by android, unfortunately I don't see your tablet there. It may work, but I have no Idea how to get it there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on muine. Graphics are glitchy. You need to run in vesa mode all the time. Wireless card is not compatible, though you can change it for other compatible one or try using a usb wifi dongle. Bluetooth doesn't work either. Touch works, sometimes you need to use the pen first and then your finger.